# warning: '0' flag used with '%p' gnu_printf format

Tags: c++, c

Please look at the code snippet below.

```
printf("%s received signal: 0x%0p", __func__, signal);
```

When compiling, i am getting the

> warning:'0' flag used with '%p' gnu_printf format.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this **warning**?

Comment: why are you using pointer format specifier to print the signal?

Comment: The signal is a void * pointer. virtual void handleSignal(void* signal)

Answer (score 4):

The `%p` flag is used for printing representations of pointers (e.g. something in the form `0xffff0000abcdef`); it takes no modification flags like, say, `%f`, where you can set the number of decimal digits you want printed.

If your signals are POSIX signals (i.e. of type `int`), you want to use `%d` for decimal values and `%x` for hexadecimal values (Edit: `%#x` for hexadecimal representation in the form `0xNNN...`).